How to make an azure function that deploys my bicep script from Azure Storage Account
I'm trying to deploy my bicep script with module that are located in my Azure storage account. And this doesn't work at all. I'm using Powershel, should I use something else?
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName test01
  -TemplateFile "https://xxxyyyzzzz.blob.core.windows.net/my-bicepscript/main.bicep"
  -TemplateParameterObject $params


Please share the main.bicep code along with the error you are encountering.

I do not think you can use remote template file like this.


How to make an azure function that deploys my bicep script from Azure Storage Account.

You cannot deploy the Bicep file from a storage account as it's not supported, but you can deploy a JSON file from a storage account using -TemplateUri. Refer to the MS Doc for more details
Alternatively, you can deploy a Bicep file by downloading it locally and use the same file for deployment in a single execution using the script below.
    $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "venkatrg" -Name "demorgtest"
    $ctx = $storageAccount.Context
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "bicep" -Blob "Resourcegroup.bicep" -Context $ctx -Destination "<Local_Path>"
    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "venkatrg" -TemplateFile "<Local_Path>/Resourcegroup.bicep"
    
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "venkatrg" -TemplateFile .\Resourcegroup.bicep

Output:

After executing the above script, the Bicep deployment has been completed and created Vnet with 2 subnets.
I have used the VNet module for testing.


Case1:
PS C:\Users\wenbo> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "wb-common-test-for-delete-rg" -TemplateUri "https://wbxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/publictest/main.bicep"

result:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The -TemplateUri parameter is not supported with .bicep files. Please download the file and pass it using -TemplateFile.

Case2:
PS C:\Users\wenbo> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "wb-common-test-for-delete-rg" -TemplateUri "https://wbxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/publictest/main.json"

result:
DeploymentName          : main
ResourceGroupName       : wb-common-test-for-delete-rg
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 7/23/2024 2:20:07 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
...                  

Summarization:
Whether using bicep file in local or json file in remote. Bicep in remote uri is not supported.
